# Dynamics Ax(R2) Excel add-in: How do I work with arrays?

Tags: excel, add-in, axapta, ax

In previous versions, the Dynamics Ax Excel add-in has returned an error when working with tables containing an array (A column named 'name' already belongs to this Data Table). This seems to have been fixed to a degree in R2, because the tables can now be used directly without errors.

However, array fields do not appear in the Excel add-in. I'm working on a project where I need to be able to access these fields in the add-in. I have tried using a query directly and making a document service and adding as data, but neither worked.

Examples of tables with arrays are ProjTable and ProjectWorkerSetup.

Has anyone figured out a simple way to make arrays work in the Dynamics Ax Excel add-in? It does not matter greatly whether the array is flattened out to one column for each index in the array or if only one column appears which will then be inserted at the beginning of the array on updates.

Any help would be much appreciated